# Output a String list ([String]) from a list of char and int [([Char], Int)] in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
numeros :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
numeros x y 
    | x < y = [n | n <- [1..x]]
    | otherwise = [n | n <- [1..x+1], n /= y]

andares :: [([Char],Int)] -> [Int]
andares xs = [b | (a,b) <- xs]

lado :: [([Char],Int)] -> [[Char]]
lado xs = [a | (a,b) <- xs]


legendaCampainha :: Int -> Int -> [([Char],Int)] -> [String]
legendaCampainha x y xs = ...
```

I need to output something like this:

```
> legendaCampainha 10 4 [("Dto", 10), ("Esq", 8), ("Cent", 3)]

["1Dto","1Esq","1Cent","2Dto","2Esq","2Cent","3Dto","3Esq",
"3Cent","5Dto","5Esq","6Dto","6Esq","7Dto","7Esq","8Dto",
"8Esq","9Dto","9Esq","10Dto","11Dto"]
```

The 10 is the number of floors, 4 is the unlucky number (so, floors are 1,2,3,5,6...11), "dto" "esq" "cent" are to say if the apartment is on the right side, left or middle, and the numbers in front (10,8,3) are to say how many apartments are on the right, left or middle. For example, there are 10 apartments on the right side ("dto") and 8 on the left side ("esq").

I already made 3 functions to help me do this, numeros are the floor numbers without the unlucky number (In this case it's [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]. Andares are the numbers of how many apartments are on one specific side (10,8,3). Lado is to read what sides there are, in this case, ["Dto,"Esq","Cent"].

I just need a hint to finish the function legendaCampainha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won’t solve your problem for you, but here’s a hint as you requested: This will be easiest if you define one more helper function, of type `[Char] -> [Int] -> [Char]`. This function will take a string and a list of floors, and append each floor number to the string. So e.g. given arguments `"Dto"` and `[1,2,3,5,6]`, it will produce the result `["1Dto", "2Dto", "3Dto", "5Dto", "6Dto"]`. Then you should be able to finish `legendaCampainha` by applying that function to each element of your `xs` input, and then combining the results.

---

But beyond that, I’d like to talk a bit about the rest of your code. It looks absolutely fine functionally, but I want to take a closer look at its readability.

First, `numeros`:

```
numeros :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
numeros x y 
    | x < y = [n | n <- [1..x]]
    | otherwise = [n | n <- [1..x+1], n /= y]
```

To me, there’s one thing I immediately notice about this function: that `[n | n <- [1..x]]` list comprehension. If you look at it, it’s taking the list `[1..x]`, getting each value from the list in turn, and then just returning that value unchanged. In other words, `[n | n <- [1..x]]` could more easily be written as simply `[1..x]`. Much easier to read!

Additionally, the second part of this function could be simplified a bit, by using the predefined function `filter`. If you haven’t encountered this function before, `filter fn list` will apply the `fn` function to each element of `list`, and then delete each element of `list` for which `fn` returns true. Which exactly matches what that list comprehension is doing! In particular, you want to filter with the `(/= y)` function, which takes a single argument and returns `True` when that argument is not equal to `y`. So you can replace `[n | n <- [1..x+1], n /= y]` with `filter (/= y) [1..x+1]`.

Finally, you can replace the guards with an if expression: `if x < y then [n | n <- [1..x]] else [n | n <- [1..x+1], n /= y]`. But that’s a matter of personal preference rather than anything else — some people find guards easier to read, others prefer if expressions.

Next, `andares` and `lado`:

```
andares :: [([Char],Int)] -> [Int]
andares xs = [b | (a,b) <- xs]

lado :: [([Char],Int)] -> [[Char]]
lado xs = [a | (a,b) <- xs]
```

Similarly to that second list comprehension, these functions can be simplified by judicious use of predefined functions. In this case, the relevant one is `map`: `map fn list` will apply `fn` to each value of `list`, then collect those into a new list. So for instance `map (+1) [1,5,10] == [2,6,11]`. Additionally, there are two more useful functions to be aware of: `fst` will return the first value of a 2-tuple, and `snd` will return the second value of a 2-tuple. Putting these together, it is clear that `andares xs = map snd xs` and `lado xs = map fst xs` — or, more simply, `andares = map snd` and `lado = map fst`.

And one more comment: In Haskell, `String` is a synonym for `[Char]`. I see you have already used `String` in your type signature for `legendaCampainha`, but more consistent use can often make type signatures easier to understand when you are working with strings a lot.

So, putting together all of my suggestions, I might rewrite your code as follows:

```
numeros :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
numeros x y = if x < y then [1..x] else filter (/=y) [1..x+1]

andares :: [(String,Int)] -> [Int]
andares = map snd

lado :: [(String,Int)] -> [String]
lado = map fst

legendaCampainha :: Int -> Int -> [(String,Int)] -> [String]
legendaCampainha x y xs = ...
```

Now, I just want to say: all this is, fundamentally, a matter of personal preference. If you think your original code was easier to read and understand, then — great! Use that! My aim here was just to suggest some alternatives you might like better, and introduce some other areas of Haskell you may not have been aware of before.

(And finally, one more hint, now that I’ve talked a bit about `map` and `filter`: looking back at my suggested function at the beginning of the post, it should be possible to write it using only `map`, `show` and `++`. Can you figure out how to do that?)

Comment: How can I put a list of chars and a list of ints together as you did in the first example?

Comment: @JohnSmith As I said, I’d rather not solve your problem for you, so I won’t give you a full solution. But I already gave a hint: ‘it should be possible to write it using only `map`, `show` and `++`’. (Though you can do it with list comprehensions rather than `map` if you feel more comfortable doing that.) The essential idea is that, for each `Int`, you should convert it to a `String`, then append each resulting `String` to the `[Char]` given as an argument.

Comment: I can't use map on this problem and I can't find out how to do it in another way. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @JohnSmith Sorry, I didn’t know that. But you can replace any `map` with a list comprehension: `map fn list = [ fn x | x <- list ]`.